# Extreme headache from ASSP Extreme Ban

Tags: smtp, spam

I've got a local user on my server that as of today cannot send email from any of their devices. Only Webmail (which doesn't touch any of their devices) works.

Here are the various email failures I'm receiving in the logs.

```
Dec-04-12 19:52:47 75966-05166 [SpoofedSender] 111.111.111.111 <someUser@localDomain.com> to: altExternaluser@gmail.com [scoring:20] -- No Spoofing Allowed -- [Test];
Dec-04-12 19:52:47 75966-05166 [Extreme] 111.111.111.111 <someUser@localDomain.com> to: altExternaluser@gmail.com [spam found] -- score for 111.111.111.111 is 1980, surpassing extreme level of 500 -- [Test] -> spam/Test__1.eml;
Dec-04-12 19:52:48 75968-05169 111.111.111.111 <someUser@localDomain.com> to: externalUser@externalDomain.com [scoring:10] -- IP in HELO does not match connection: '[192.168.0.10]' -- [Re Demo Feedbacks for End of November Sales];
Dec-04-12 19:52:48 75968-05169 [SpoofedSender] 111.111.111.111 <someUser@localDomain.com> to: externalUser@externalDomain.com [scoring:20] -- No Spoofing Allowed -- [Re Demo Feedbacks for End of November Sales];
Dec-04-12 19:52:48 75968-05169 [Extreme] 111.111.111.111 <someUser@localDomain.com> to: externalUser@externalDomain.com [spam found] -- score for 111.111.111.111 is 2020, surpassing extreme level of 500 -- [Re Demo Feedbacks for End of November Sales] ->spam/Re_Demo_Feedbacks_for_End_of_N__2.eml;
Dec-04-12 19:52:57 75977-05179 [SpoofedSender] 111.111.111.111 <someUser@localDomain.com> to: altExternaluser@gmail.com [scoring:20] -- No Spoofing Allowed -- [test];
Dec-04-12 19:52:57 75977-05179 [Extreme] 111.111.111.111 <someUser@localDomain.com> to: altExternaluser@gmail.com [spam found] -- score for 111.111.111.111 is 2040, surpassing extreme level of 500 -- [test] -> spam/test__3.eml;

…………….

Dec-04-12 19:55:35 76135-05338 [SpoofedSender] 111.111.111.111 <someUser@localDomain.com> to: altExternaluser@gmail.com [scoring:20] -- No Spoofing Allowed -- [test];
Dec-04-12 19:55:35 76135-05338 [MsgID] 111.111.111.111 <someUser@localDomain.com> to: altExternaluser@gmail.com [scoring] (Message-ID not valid: 'E8472A91545B44FBAE413F6D8760C7C3@bts');
Dec-04-12 19:55:35 76135-05338 [InvalidHELO] 111.111.111.111 <someUser@localDomain.com> to: altExternaluser@gmail.com [spam found] -- Invalid HELO: 'bts' -- [test] -> discarded/test__4.eml;
```

*note: 111.111.111.111 is a replacement for the users home IP address*

Here is the headers of one of the messages

```
X-Assp-Score: 10 (HELO contains IP: '[192.168.0.10]')
X-Assp-Score: 10 (IP in HELO does not match connection: '[192.168.0.10]')
X-Assp-Score: 20 (No Spoofing Allowed)
X-Assp-Score: 10 (bombSubjectRe: 'sale')
X-Assp-Score: 20 (blacklisted HELO '[192.168.0.10]')
X-Assp-Score: 45 (DNSBLcache: failed, 111.111.111.111 listed in safe.dnsbl.sorbs.net)
X-Assp-DNSBLcache: failed, 174.0.35.31 listed in safe.dnsbl.sorbs.net
X-Assp-Received-SPF: fail (cache) ip=174.0.35.31 mailfrom=someUser@localDomain.com
    helo=[192.168.0.10]
X-Assp-Score: 10 (SPF fail)
X-Assp-Envelope-From: omeUser@localDomain.com
X-Assp-Intended-For: externalUser@externalDomain.com
X-Assp-Version: 1.7.5.7(1.0.07) on ASSP.nospam
X-Assp-ID: ASSP.nospam (77953-07232)
X-Assp-Spam: YES
X-Assp-Original-Subject: Re: Demo Feedbacks for End of November Sales
X-Spam-Status:yes
X-Assp-Spam-Reason: MessageScore (125) over limit (50)
X-Assp-Message-Totalscore: 125
Received: from [192.168.0.10] ([111.111.111.111] helo=[192.168.0.10]) with
    IPv4:25 by ASSP.nospam; 4 Dec 2012 20:25:52 -0700
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=Apple-Mail-40FE7453-4BE7-4AD6-B297-FB81DAA554EC
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: Re: Demo Feedbacks for End of November Sales
References: <003c01cdd22e$eafbc6f0$c0f354d0$@com>
From: Some User <someUser@localDomain.com>
In-Reply-To: <003c01cdd22e$eafbc6f0$c0f354d0$@com>
Message-Id: <9045DFA9-D447-4EFF-9976-70BDE2FA54D0@localDomain.com>
Date: Tue, 4 Dec 2012 19:32:28 -0700
To: External User <externalUser@externalDomain.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0 (1.0)
X-Mailer: iPhone Mail (10A523)
```

Why is it that a local sender has been banned on our local server, and how can I fix this?

Comment: What's your anti-spam service, and what mailer are you using?

Comment: Anti-Spam service is [ASSP](http://www.magicvillage.de/~Fritz_Borgstedt/assp/ASSP-Project-Home/), and mail server is [MailEnable](http://www.mailenable.com/). Messages are being rejected before hitting MailEnable.

Comment: Why is your user connecting to port 25 instead of 587?

Comment: Because SSL isn't configured on this particular server.

Comment: I didn't say anything about SSL.

Comment: Port 587 is the alternative SMTP connection port, and TLS or SSL is not required for it. Many systems relaying mail for authenticated users (or otherwise trusted users) do so over that, since TCP/25's reputation is so bad due to spam.

Comment: hmmm, this I didn't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it just me, or does the header not tell you exactly why this user is getting his mail rejected?

> X-Assp-Spam-Reason: MessageScore (125) over limit (50)

His message is scoring too high as spam.  The specific reasons for which are also listed further up in the header...

```
X-Assp-Score: 10 (HELO contains IP: '[192.168.0.10]')
X-Assp-Score: 10 (IP in HELO does not match connection: '[192.168.0.10]')
X-Assp-Score: 20 (No Spoofing Allowed)
X-Assp-Score: 10 (bombSubjectRe: 'sale')
X-Assp-Score: 20 (blacklisted HELO '[192.168.0.10]')
X-Assp-Score: 45 (DNSBLcache: failed, 111.111.111.111 listed in safe.dnsbl.sorbs.net)
X-Assp-DNSBLcache: failed, 174.0.35.31 listed in safe.dnsbl.sorbs.net
X-Assp-Received-SPF: fail (cache) ip=174.0.35.31 mailfrom=someUser@localDomain.com
    helo=[192.168.0.10]
X-Assp-Score: 10 (SPF fail)
```

+10 for the HELO containing an IP, +10 for the IP not matching the connection IP, +20 for no spoofing, +10 for the word `sale` in the subject, +20 for a blacklisted HELO (with that IP again), +45 for the IP being on a blacklist (safe.dnsbl.sorbs.net) and +10 for an SPF fail.  Adds up to 125, which is greater than your spam threshold of 50.

Seems pretty clear to me.  Did I miss something?

### EDIT:

In response to your comment,

I see two problems, the first of which being that your external IP is on the [`SORBS-DUHL` blacklist](http://mxtoolbox.com/Public/BlacklistDetails.aspx?bl=SORBS-DUHL&page=BLD&upgrade=BLD&SO=MMM), though it's giving me a weird return code, and seems to be the only blacklist you're on... so I'd contact them and politely ask what the hell's up.  That's 45 of 125 spam score there.

The second problem seems to be that your ASSP is configured to score as spam anything coming from a private IP (192.168.0.10), and as your user is at home when this happens (according to your comment), he is likely behind some SOHO router or switch that's assigning his PC a private IP (192.168.0.10).  That's at least 40 of the 125 spam score, and possibly 60 or 70 - I can't say for sure why the SPF failure and the spoofing failure are occurring, but I suspect they're both related to the fact that this user is trying to send mail as from your domain, but with an IP address that's not valid for mail coming from your corporate network.

Either way, the only solutions to this I can see are either sorting out the user's home network so that his PC sees itself at his external, ISP-provided IP address or changing your spam filter's rules to accommodate this user.  I recommend the option that doesn't involve having to support some user's home network.  Or, come to think of it telling the user that his home setup isn't compatible with your mail setup, and he'll have to either deal with it, fix it himself, or use webmail.  Actually, that's what I'd do, on account of it being less work, and me generally not wanting to change the whole spam filtering scheme for one user.

So a mail that would normally score 10 (for containing `sale` in the subject), is scoring over the threshold because of either issue.  So it looks like you'll have to resolve both the blacklist and the IP issues we're seeing here to get mail flowing reliably from local senders.

Comment: Yeah you're right as to the reason, the problem here is that this is a **local sender**, so you're seeing things like `blacklisted HELO 192.168.0.10`... this shouldn't be. Also, the `No Spoofing Allowed` isn't totally clear to me.

Comment: Well, the way it looks to me is that a) your external IP has been blacklisted (`X-Assp-DNSBLcache: failed, 174.0.35.31 listed in safe.dnsbl.sorbs.net`), which I verified, so that's one problem and b) if I had to guess, it looks like the private IP in the HELO, the "spoofing" and the SPF failure are all related to your mail server responding to internal senders on its private IP, rather than the public one, so that's problem 2.

Comment: Maybe it's late and I've been staring at this for too long. You're absolutely right, but I'm just not quite grasping the last statement *"your mail server responding to internal senders on its private IP, rather than the public one"*

Comment: @ChaseFlorell Well, it's been a while, so I may be a bit fuzzy (and hopefully I'm not screwing this up), but when I connect to our Exchange server internally, at its private IP address of 192.168.100.40, the HELO response it gives contains its public IP address, not the private one.  For whatever reason, it looks like your mail server is giving a response that it's at 192.168.0.10, but of course, the publicly routable IP is what's in your SPF entry and presumably your anti-spoofing checks, so the fact that your mailserver is announcing itself at an IP other than the publicly reachable one is a

Comment: that 192.168... IP is our user's home computer IP, not our server.

Comment: also ALL other local senders are fine. It's only a single local sender... who by the way has two different email addresses on two different domain names on our server. When they're at home, they can't send from either domain.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell  That makes more sense, and is easier to fix.  It seems you have ASSP configured to score mail coming from 192.168.0.10 "too highly" on the spam meter, so this sender is unable to send - he's getting +40 alone from his client computer reporting its IP address as a private IP (and I bet that's where the +20 `spoofing` flag is coming from too), out of a threshold of 50, so... he's not going to be able to send until you get his home network sorted out, or accommodate your spam filter rules to his home network setup.  By the way, you should include the "he's at home" in your Q.

Comment: Turns out the client was having serious issues with their internet connection. Interference or range issues were causing all the issues. Believe it or not, they relocated their wireless router and their problems went away. Very strange.